# Have any sustainability.SE questions ever made it to the hot network questions list?

Tags: discussion

Just curious as to whether this has ever happened, and if so, what the result was -- spammy answers, or increased engagement and new traffic?

Comment: I asked about this on MSE, and [an answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338484/346823) includes a link to [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/sustainability/query/1149151/hnq-hits), updated weekly, that will let us track this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find Hot Questions posted after [February 28th, 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324641/295232) via the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), with the query I posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324663/295232).

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/sustainability/query/1155183/hot-questions) it is; right now, it gives 7 results, including ones that were mentioned already:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

<strike>​I don't think we've had any hot network questions on Sustainability SE, but I admittedly I'm not sure.</strike> <strike>The problem is that there is no way to search for questions that were once a hot network question (HNQ) or check if an individual question has been HNQ ([feature request for that is on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297655/164138)). Moderators can check if a particular question was a HNQ in the past, but not search for such questions.</strike>

The only experience I've had with this is when a question I asked on Politics SE  became hot ([it's this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/13066/9042)). I asked it in the morning and received 2 answers. During the day it apparently became a hot network question and it started receiving quite a lot of views and upvotes in a short time. I earned both the 'notable question' and 'good question' badge within a few hours. One more answer was added while it was 'hot' and several comments were made on the answers, but that's about it.

**Update Aug 21, 2019**: I noticed that [this question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/8433/how-can-i-support-the-recycling-but-not-the-new-production-of-aluminum) has received a lot of views in a very short time. Further investigation shows that it was [marked as a hot network question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/posts/8433/revisions) about 19 hours ago. When hovering on the question in the HNQ-list a pop-up is shown that says "*This question has been arbitrarily awarded 7.184 hotness points*". I think it's safe to say that the result is more views (2K in 1 day) and more upvotes on both the question and answers (question has 9 upvotes now, the 2 answers have 11 and 5 upvotes),

**Update Nov 20, 2019:** It is now possible to search for HNQs, see [Glorfindel's answer](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/a/330)

Answer (score 1):

The question

> [Preventing idling - ideas to keep warm in a car when the engine is off and it is cold outside](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/9655/preventing-idling-ideas-to-keep-warm-in-a-car-when-the-engine-is-off-and-it-is)

was [marked "hot"](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/posts/9655/revisions) one hour ago.

Comment: Indeed, good find! I did notice the [fuel cell question](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/are-fuel-cell-electricity-generators-a-sustainable-way-of-making-electricity) attracted attention from new users, got 3 answers in a short time and already has 1K views. Weirdly, the 'preventing idling' question is less successful in this sense.